# Get whole tags including selected tag in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

My html content is

```
<div class="div1>
      div1
</div>

<div class="div2>
      div2
</div>
```

My jquery code is

```
$("div").click(function(){
       alert($(this).html());
});
```

This will return either "div1" or "div2" based on the click. But i would like to get whole tags like `<div class="div1"> div1 </div>` from "this" object. Is there anyway to do that...?

Comment: `alert(this.outerHTML);`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to get the outer HTML of the element. You can achieve that by creating a temporary clone of the element itself. For example:

```
$('div').on('click', function() {
    alert( $('<div>').append( $(this).clone() ).html() );
});
```

Alternatively, you can use the built-in [`outerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.outerHTML) property, for example:

```
$('div').on('click', function() {
    alert( this.outerHTML );
});
```

Answer (score -1):

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Tushar490/8gcnhkcg/):**

```
$('div').click(function () {
   console.log(this);
});
```

Comment: `$(this)` refers to the jQuery object itself, not its HTML. -1

Comment: i have edited . @BenM

Comment: Still no dice. `this` refers to the DOM object, not its `outerHTML` property. There are other answers on the page that better answer the question.

Comment: But what he wants , why don't you look that ? @BenM

Comment: I did, did you? `But i would like to get whole tags like <div class="div1"> div1 </div> from "this" object` Notice, he also uses `html()` in his sample...

Comment: `<div class="div1"> div1 </div>` . I think this is the only output you will get if you try my code and the same OP wants @BenM

Comment: Not true. Your code logs an object, not a string. For example: `console.log(typeof this);` => `object`.